# How to change table background image upon mouseover of another link

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover, css-tables

I have this for changing the background image of `div.fullscreen`:

```
<div id="swatches">
  <a href="http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/storage/images/PH3380A.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.wmagency.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/test.jpg"
         onmouseover="document.images['bigPic'].src='http://josefsipek.net/docs/s390-    linux/hercules-s390/ssh-dasd1.png';"
         width="72" height="54" alt="Item ksc1" />
  </a>
</div>
```

However, is there a way to change the background image of a table on `hover` of another image link?

Comment: Given that you're already using JavaScript why are you not prepared to accept a non-CSS solution ("CSS only" from your question title)?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot I used some JS but generally would prefer css as some browsers have javascript turned off. Whichever is most efficient would be great thanks! Oh and question has been ammended right away. Ta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, look at an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qktQd/).

This is done by giving the `img` an `id` and the `table` an `id`. Then we listen for when the mouse is over the `img` and when it does, change the `background-image` of the `table`.

Only want to use inline JavaScript? Use this:

```
<div id="swatches">
  <a href="http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/storage/images/PH3380A.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.wmagency.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/test.jpg"
         onmouseover='document.getElementById("table_id_here").style["background-image"]="url(\'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/\');'
         width="72" height="54" alt="Item ksc1" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shaz, can't seem to get this to work. Please see: http://zabb.co.uk/untitled20.html Thanks so much for all your efforts thus far..

Comment: @Kelly Remove the `$(document)` ready function then move the only `script` block **after** the table (right above the ending body tag)